# Xpath: match a node only if one sub-node contains special string

Tags: xpath

First sample:

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
  <li><a href="http://www.sample.com/1">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.sample.com/2">Movies</a></li>              
  <li><a href="http://www.sample.com/3">Thrilling Action</a></li>          
  <li><strong>Armageddon</strong></li>
</ul>
```

Second sample:

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
  <li><a href="http://www.sample.com/1">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.sample.com/2">Food</a></li>              
  <li><a href="http://www.sample.com/3">Sweet rice</a></li>          
  <li><strong>Uncle Ben's Boil-In-Bag Rice</strong></li>
</ul>
```

This is how far I have come:

```
/html/body//ul[@class='breadcrumbs']/li[2]/a[contains(., 'Movies') or contains(., 'Cool Gadgets')]
```

Extracts `Movies` - but I also want it to extract `Thrilling Action`.

Explained: If the `<a>`-tag of second `<li>`-tag contains the strings "Movies" or "Cool Gadgets" I want to extract the `<a>`-tags of the second and the third `<li>`-tag.

```
/html//ul[@class='breadcrumbs']/li[2]/a
/html//ul[@class='breadcrumbs']/li[3]/a
```

If li[2] dosen't contain "Movies" or "Cool Gadgets", I don't want to extract anything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it right, you want to match all the `<li>` tags inside an `<ul>` *if* one of the `<li>` contains a special string. You could use:

> //ul[@class="breadcrumbs" and (li[2]/a/text() = "Movies" or li[2]/a/text() = "Cool Gadgets")]/li[position() > 1]/a/text()

**Explanation**

1) The first part, `//ul[@class="breadcrumbs" and (li[2]/a/text() = "Movies" or li[2]/a/text() = "Cool Gadgets")]`, will check you're in a `<ul>` tag that fits your needs.

`@class="breadcrumbs"` does what you might expect, and `li[2]/a/text() = "Movies" or li[2]/a/text() = "Cool Gadgets"` will return true if your filtering string is present.

Of course, if needed, you can change `a/text() = "Movies"` into `a[contains(text(), "Movies")]`.

2) Once we know we're in the right place, all we have to do is select the fields you want. This is done by `li[position() > 1]` which will catch every `<li>` except the first. Select the text, and you're good to go!

Comment: Excellent! I was breaking my head over how I'd do a `(self | following-sibling::)` subselect, this works much better. Though probably it more correctly answers the question when using `li[2]/a/text()` instead of `li/a/text()`.

Comment: Yep, it might avoid false positive indeed. Edited.

Answer (score -2):

The Document Type Declaration (see `DocumentType`) associated with this document.

- For XML documents without a document type declaration this returns null.
- For HTML documents, a DocumentType object may be returned, independently of the presence or absence of document type declaration in the HTML document.

This provides direct access to the `DocumentType` node, child node of this Document. This node can be set at document creation time and later changed through the use of child nodes manipulation methods, such as `Node.insertBefore`, or `Node.replaceChild`.

Note, however, that while some implementations may instantiate different types of Document objects supporting additional features than the "Core", such as "HTML" `[DOM Level 2 HTML]` , based on the DocumentType specified at creation time, changing it afterwards is very unlikely to result in a change of the features supported.
[coolgadgets](http://bit.ly/1wxofJ0)